# How does the human body respond to creatine?

Tags: supplements, creatine

People do ask questions about supplements whether they are healthy or do they harm the body?

I want to know how the human body responds after taking "fitness" supplements with creatine.

I know it's hard to generalize the effects, as our bodies differ from person to person. But again, I'm really interested in this subject and I want to study it more.

So instead of asking a book recommendation, I'm asking where to begin to study the subject. Keep in mind that I want to study the theoretical part of the substances before taking them.

Comment: I think your question is too broad an out of the scope of this site. As per Help Center: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Also book requests are discouraged on most stackexchange sites, not sure how that is handled here.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I left the book recommendation part. And I mentioned creatine as the supplement to study instead of all existing supplements. I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: okay, maybe I was a bit rash in downvoting, as the question does have merit, although it's still very broad. I removed my downvote and tried to give a few pointers where to start looking in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you check out [Examine](http://examine.com). It's a supplement encyclopedia, and is a great jumping off point for understanding what a particular supplement is and how it works. Importantly, all of their information is based on the best available research, which is extensively linked.

Since you're interested in how the body responds to a particular supplement, you may find their "Human Effect Matrix" particularly interesting. It shows the extent of various bodily effects as seen in actual human studies.

[Creatine](http://examine.com/supplements/Creatine/) is just one of the many supplements that they provide information on.

> Creatine is a molecule in an energy system (creatine phosphate) that can rapidly produce energy (ATP) to support cellular function. This underlies the performance enhancing and neuroprotective properties of creatine. Creatine is remarkably safe for most people and is a well-researched supplement.

---

Not as friendly to the layman but [PubMed](http://pubmed.gov) is also a great place to find information (i.e. research) about various topics including supplements.

Comment: Examine.com is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read up on supplements, what they do, how they work and how well they are researched, [this link](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/bbmainsupp.htm) (scroll down) might help you. There's pretty much information about every supplement you could think of. Most of the articles, especially those by [Jim Stoppani](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/jim-stoppani.htm) (scroll down for his articles), are very well researched and cite numerous studies.

Do consider the fact, that the site is in the business of selling supplements though, and almost every author is associated with supplement companies, so their views are probably biased.

Comment: Okay, this is already a good example. I'll wait for other answers before accepting yours as the answer.